# Как правильно создать кастомное поле в AWS QuickSight?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Хочу сделать собственное поле в AWS QuickSight и чтобы результатом данного поля было деление уже созданного поля на некое число.

```
({time_from_open_to_close_issue_minutes} / 60)
```

Но это не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было перевести первое значение из строки в инт.